# Macbook 2.26 unibody late 2009 model 6,1 comes 1066MHz RAM, can it run 1333hz

Tags: laptop, memory

I am not asking if I put in 2 4GB modules of 1333MHz DDR3 RAM will it run without glitch, but instead I am asking will this Hz of am run at 1333hz without issue so the additional benefits of paying more are realized.

I see a bunch about yes it runs, but nobody says whether it runs at the intended speed, or if the limitations of the motherboard and chipset simply clock it back to 1066.66MHz or apple 1067hz so you paid to say you use 1333MHz.

If outside Apple you can find these answers easy, but apple not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the bus of the machine is 1066mhz (from here http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.26-white-13-polycarbonate-unibody-late-2009-specs.html), my best educated guess is that the memory will only run at that speed and not at the 1333mhz top speed.